# Angular "npm i" Unsupported engine error message

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to install all the dependencies of my angular application.

Now once I enter `npm i` to install all the dependencies I am receiving this error message. [image]

Initially, I thought this is an issue with Installing Angular CLI globally using npm, so I run the

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

and I received this message -
[image]

Now anyone has any idea what is wrong with the angular CLI message and also what do I need to do to successfully install the `npm i` to my angular application successfully?

Comment: What is unclear from the error message? The package you're supporting wants Node of at least 10.13 and up to the latest 12, but you're using 16.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is unclear is whether I do need to downgrade the node or upgrade the node version of the Applicaiton.

Comment: You'll have to look into whether the packages that are complaining have newer versions support more up-to-date Node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you have the wrong version of @nguniversal and its not compatible with the current version of angular you have which looks to be 12.x.

so you have to type for good measure:

if any have an error its because one of the packages are not there and that's okay with the next step

```
npm uninstall @nguniversal/common
npm uninstall @nguniversal/builders
npm uninstall @nguniversal/express-engine
```

now type

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

that's it it will add itself - there is still a lot of work post this though so please follow these instructions carefully.

https://angular.io/guide/universal

Answer (score 2):

Angular requires an `active LTS or maintenance LTS` version of Node.js:
https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#prerequisites.

So install LTS releases of Node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/